# Java сервер без перекомпиляции с автоподгружением изменений?

Tags: java, tomcat, wildfly, jetty

Обучался работе на Intellij Idea Ultimate, пока обучался лицензия была бесплатна. И настало время юзать Idea community, увидев все недостатки для использования в сравнении с ultimate.
Начал искать способы решения пиратка не подходит, а платить для не специалиста дорого.
Нашёл много материалов о том как использовать embedded Jetty или embedded Tomcat (а так же с использованием maven плагинов для юза Jetty), но ни один из выборов не подходит. (И кстати ни один из информаторов в полной мере всё досканоль и не объясняет. Может есть книги по теме хотя бы на английском!?)

То путь из xml не подгружается, а если через аннотацию то ок.. и наоборот..
То требуется прописывать всё руками для проверки как работает, той или иной сервлет.. (т.е. для проверки каждого отдельного сервлета надо персонально накатывать "запускатор".
То при попытке подключения сервера к уже ранее до этого созданного проекта (с помощью Intellij Idea Ultimate), опять не работает, обязательно что-то не работает.

Что лучше из серверов использовать и как с автоподгрузкой изменений без перекомпиляции..!?
(Что бы в будущем не было "трудностей")

Есть ли из всего этого выход!?

Comment: У JVM плохо с горячей заменой кода. Эту проблему частично решают очень недешёвые средства, вроде JRebel. И более-менее сносно работает hot swap у Spring Boot и Play Framework.

Comment: Play Framework - хорошее решение.

Comment: Выход есть всегда, попробуй eclipse.